# How can I check if database exists and user of that database has permission to connect that database - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-connection

I'm getting this kind of error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` when I'm trying to check this

```
if(DB::connection())
{
   //do something
}
```

Now what I want to do is I want to check if the database on which application is trying to connect **exists**. If yes then it should check if the user defined in the application has privileges to connect to that database. And if yes then I want to migrate all the tables.

Please help me with this. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can try catch the exception:

```
public function test($connectionName)// connection name
{
    $state = true;
    try {
        \DB::connection($connectionName);
    } catch( \PDOException $e) {
        $state = false;
    }

    return $state;
}

public function index()
{
    dd($this->test('mysql'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because if the database doesn't exists, `connection` doesn't know it yet.